# Shuffling 2 identical arrays without them matching, PHP help?

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I have 2 identical arrays with integers.  What I'm trying to do is shuffle both arrays so no numbers are repeating and that they don't match up.  For instance:

If Array 1 has 4 ints {1, 2, 3, 4) and Array2 has 4 ints {1, 2, 3, 4). I need them to be shuffled so the elements in Array1 don't match the elements in Array 2.

The code I have so far:

```
    $Array1 = array();
    $Array2 = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{   
    $Array1[] = $row['id'];
    $Array2[] = $row['id']; 
}
shuffle($Array1);
shuffle($Array2);
array_unique($Array1);
array_unique($Array2);
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($Array1); $i++)
    {
        if($Array1[$i] == $Array2[$i])
        {
            array_rand($Array1);
            array_rand($Array2);
            array_unique($Array1);
            array_unique($Array2);
        }
    }
```

Without the array_rand() and array_unique() in the if statement, the output is correctly shuffled with no repeating numbers in both arrays, however I still get matches.  Any help?

Comment: By "never match" you mean that `array1[n]` is never the same as `array2[n]`? If that's the only requirement, that's as easy as shifting all values one over. Is that the only requirement?

Comment: deceze:  yes thats what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Array1 = $Array2 = array(1,2,3,4);
$Array1 = array_unique($Array1); 
$Array2 = array_unique($Array2);

if (count($Array1) == 1 && count($Array2) == 1 && $Array1 == $Array2) {
   die("Arrays can never be randomized differently");
}  

shuffle($Array1);

do {
   shuffle($Array2);
}  
while (array_intersect_assoc($Array1, $Array2));

var_dump($Array1, $Array2);
```

Comment: Just note that randomly reshuffling until you happen to find a valid result is potentially a hugely wasteful operation for large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this should be sufficient:

```
shuffle($array1);
$array2 = $array1;
$array2[] = array_shift($array2);
```

That depends on how random you really need it though.

Comment: If there's the potential for duplicates, I'd add a call to `array_unique` on `$array1`, as they will cause `$array2[n-1] = $array1[n]`.

Comment: I need the same numbers to be in 2 different arrays, both extremely random. This still shows that some of the elements match up (array1[2] and array2[2] would both have "4" in that spot).

Comment: @deceze you knew what reply you'd get for that answer ;)

Comment: @zaf Sort of. :o) This should certainly avoid matches though, as long as all values are unique. Not sure what Java means by his comment.

Comment: @deceze doesn't want the same values in the same same positions in both arrays. Anyway - apparently the answer has been found.